# pointer arthmatic needs some explanation. Moving across memory and accessing different byte in other words tcp options

Tags: c

I have this code

```
        uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)tcph + 20; // or sizeof (struct tcphdr)
        uint8_t *end = (uint8_t *)tcph + tcph->doff * 4;
        uint16_t mss = 0; 
        printf("jjjj %d %d",p ,end);
        while (p < end) {
            uint8_t kind = *p++;
            printf("kind = %d\n",kind);
            if (kind == 0) {
                break;
            }
            if (kind == 1) {
                // No-op option with no length.
            printf("\nNo-opt\n");
                continue;
            }
            printf("p before %x\n",p);  
            uint8_t size = *p++;
            printf("p after %x size = %x\n",p,size);
            if (kind == 2) {
                mss = ntohs(*(uint16_t *)p);
                printf("\nMSS =  %x MSS = %d\n",(mss),htons(mss));  
            }
            p += (size - 2);
            printf("p super after %x\n",p);
        }
```

the thing is that the tcp MSS starts at something like thing

Following is Point one

```
   sizeof(struct tcphdr)+[uint8_t(kind)+uint8_t(length)+uint16_t(thats value of MSS)]=option1 , ....
```

So the above code is extracting MSS's two byte value from above memory layout (shown in point 1)

The thing is the while loop is used to extract all options that are linked to tcp protocol

so this like `uint8_t kind = *p++;` escape the initial one byte before any option

so that now we are at `kind` value of first option (since this is only tcp option on my system so its also last)

then I am doing `uint8_t size = *p++;` so now p advanced to second byte since p is one byte size which is tcp option length. Now
to extract the actual option like mss value which has kind value == 2 shouldnt I increment one byte more to get passed the sizeof option length space too, but this code does not do it. So the question is my `p` current point is standing at length space and the code is doing this to extract the mss value which is at third byte from right (most significant bit ) why is that `mss = ntohs(*(uint16_t *)p);`

Comment: The correct format to print a pointer with `printf` is `%p`. And the pointer needs to be explicitly a `void *` pointer. Mismatching `printf` format specifier and argument type (like printing a pointer with `%d`) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so with p does it print addess?

Comment: Yes`%p` prints the pointer as an address (in an implementation-specific format). So for example `printf("jjjj %d %d",p ,end)` should be `printf("jjjj %p %p\n",(void *) p ,(void *) end)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok thanks, can u also answer this simple question about tcp. In the question's code why is it not skipping one extra byte that normally comes between start of `tcp options` and `struct tcphdr`

Comment: That is misleading: *so that now we are at kind value of first option*. After that statement is executed, `p` is already one byte behind the `kind` value, pointing to the `size` value. In next statement you fetch `size` and advance the pointer to offset 2 where MSS starts. Therefore this *my p current point is standing at length space* is just wrong. You have alreaday passed that position before.

Comment: @Gerhardh isnt there one byte empty space before options and after struct tcphdr

Comment: There is rarely empty space in protocols. Where did you get that information?

Comment: The options could be padded at the *end*, but not at the beginning.